# C++17 invoke_result and static_assert for template func param

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, static-assert

This is purely for gaining more knowledge when doing generic programming. How can I ensure the return type of a function passed in as a template argument to another function, which can take a different number of params (0 to N).

EDIT:
I am trying to use `std::invoke_result` and `static_assert()` to ensure the proper return type for registered factory methods. I've used a better example than the first one posted to give more clarity.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <typeindex>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Factory final
{
public:
    template<typename My_Type, typename Func>
    static bool Register(Func func)
    {
        // issue is these two lines of code, when trying to register Derived1 and Derived2 create functions
        typename invoke_result<Func>::type result;
        static_assert(is_same<decltype(result), unique_ptr<My_Type>>::value, "Not a unique pointer to type 'My_Type'");

        bool isRegistered = false;

        if (GetCreateFunctions().end() == GetCreateFunctions().find(typeid(My_Type)))
        {
            GetCreateFunctions()[typeid(My_Type)] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(func);
            isRegistered = true;
        }

        return isRegistered;
    }

    template<typename My_Type, typename... Args>
    static unique_ptr<My_Type> Create(Args&&... args)
    {
        unique_ptr<My_Type> type = nullptr;
        auto iter = GetCreateFunctions().find(typeid(My_Type));

        if (GetCreateFunctions().end() != iter)
        {
            typedef unique_ptr<My_Type>(*create_func)(Args&&...);
            auto create = reinterpret_cast<create_func>(iter->second);
            type = create(forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        return type;
    }

private:
    static unordered_map<type_index, void*>& GetCreateFunctions()
    {
        static unordered_map<type_index, void*> map;
        return map;
    }
};

class Base
{
public:
    Base(unique_ptr<string>&& moveString)
        :
        _moveString(move(moveString))
    {
    }

    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void DoSomething() const = 0;

protected:
    unique_ptr<string> _moveString;
};

class Derived1 final : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1(unique_ptr<string>&& moveString)
        :
        Base(move(moveString))
    {
    }

    ~Derived1() = default;

    void DoSomething() const override
    {
        if (_moveString)
        {
            // do something...
        }
    }

private:
    static const bool _isRegistered;

    static unique_ptr<Derived1> Create(unique_ptr<string>&& moveString)
    {
        return make_unique<Derived1>(move(moveString));
    }
};

const bool Derived1::_isRegistered = Factory::template Register<Derived1>(&Derived1::Create);

class Derived2 final : public Base
{
public:
    Derived2()
        :
        Base(make_unique<string>("Default"))
    {
    }

    ~Derived2() = default;

    void DoSomething() const override
    {
        if (_moveString)
        {
            // do something...
        }
    }

private:
    static const bool _isRegistered;

    static unique_ptr<Derived2> Create()
    {
        return make_unique<Derived2>();
    }
};

const bool Derived2::_isRegistered = Factory::template Register<Derived2>(&Derived2::Create);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string moveString = "moveString";
    unique_ptr<Base> myBase_Derived1 = Factory::template Create<Derived1>(make_unique<string>(move(moveString)));
    unique_ptr<Base> myBase_Derived2 = Factory::template Create<Derived2>();

    if (myBase_Derived1)
        printf("Success\n");

    if (myBase_Derived2)
        printf("Success\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: template<typename T, class... ArgTypes, typename Func>
void Example(Func)
{
 // func can have params, or have no params
 static_assert(std::is_same<
  std::invoke_result<Func, ArgTypes...>::type,
  std::unique_ptr<T>>::value,
  "Not a unique pointer to type 'T'");
}

Comment: Please do not completely rewrite questions that have already been answered.  Ask a new question.

Comment: @Adam Nevraumont will do next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work in all functional cases but, with function pointers, should work.

If you define a custom template as follows

```
template <typename>
struct baz;

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct baz<R(*)(Args...)>
 { using retType = R; };
```

your example become

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
void Example(Func func)
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same<typename baz<Func>::retType,
                              std::unique_ptr<T>>::value,  "!");
 }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

template <typename>
struct baz;

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct baz<R(*)(Args...)>
 { using retType = R; };

template <typename T, typename Func>
void Example(Func func)
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same<typename baz<Func>::retType,
                              std::unique_ptr<T>>::value,  "!");
 }

struct Foo
 {
   Foo (int i) : My_I{i}
    { }

   Foo () : My_I{99}
    { }

   ~Foo() = default;

   int My_I;
 };

std::unique_ptr<Foo> bar0 ()
{ return std::make_unique<Foo>(11); }

std::unique_ptr<Foo> bar1 (int)
{ return std::make_unique<Foo>(11); }

std::unique_ptr<Foo> bar2 (int, long)
{ return std::make_unique<Foo>(11); }

int main ()
 {
   Example<Foo>(&bar0);
   Example<Foo>(&bar1);
   Example<Foo>(&bar2);
 }
```

Unfortunately this solution works only with function pointers and not with (by example) lambda function (when not convertible to function pointers) or classes with `operator()`.

If you can use C++17 -- and I suppose is your case, if you use `std::invoke_result` -- you can also use automatic deduction guides for `std::function`.

So, in C++17, you can forget the `baz` struct and simply write

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
void Example(Func func)
 {        
   static_assert(std::is_same<
       typename decltype(std::function{func})::result_type,
       std::unique_ptr<T>>::value,  "!");
 }
```

or, in your `Register()` method

```
template<typename My_Type, typename Func>
static bool Register(Func func)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<
       typename decltype(std::function{func})::result_type,
       std::unique_ptr<My_Type>>::value,  "!");

    bool isRegistered = false;

    if (GetCreateFunctions().end() == GetCreateFunctions().find(typeid(My_Type)))
    {
        GetCreateFunctions()[typeid(My_Type)] = reinterpret_cast<void*>(func);
        isRegistered = true;
    }

    return isRegistered;
}
```

Comment: Thanks max66, I changed the code example to better illustrate my question. There is a factory with a 'Register' method that has the issue with the static_assert.

Comment: @GreekFire - cannot reproduce: for me works; try with `static_assert(std::is_same<typename baz<Func>::retType, std::unique_ptr<My_Type>>::value,  "!");`; give me some minutes and I propose another (C++17 only) solution; but this one should works also with you `Register()`

Comment: @GreekFire - answer improved with a second (C++17 only) solution; both of they works, for me, with your code.

Comment: Wow, the c++17 solution is slick... works wonderfully! (for Register() method)

Comment: @GreekFire - great improvement C++17 deduction guides!

Answer (score 2):

you had an extra `()` on

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(result), std::unique_ptr<T>/* here */ >::value, "Not a unique pointer to type 'T'");
```

and

```
typename std::invoke_result<Func/* here */>::type result;
```

`A` and `A()` are two different types. `A()` is a function returning a `A` and taking no arguments.

the final code should be

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename Func>
void Example(Func)
{
    // func can have params, or have no params
    typename std::invoke_result<Func>::type result;
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(result), std::unique_ptr<T> >::value, "Not a unique pointer to type 'T'"); // can't get this correct (tried different variations, looked over stackoverflow, etc.)
}

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int i)
        : My_I(i)
    {
    }

    Foo()
        : My_I(99)
    {
    }

    ~Foo() = default;

    int My_I;
};

unique_ptr<Foo> CreateWithInt()
{
    return make_unique<Foo>(11);
}

int main()
{
    Example<Foo>(&CreateWithInt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it works for the original code posted. But not for what I was intending. I posted a more direct code example based on a factory with registration that I was thinking would benefit by ensuring the return type matches the template type for the 'Register' method.

Comment: @greek as a general rule, if someone answers the question as posed, upvote, check mark.  If your real problem is something else, create a new question eith the original problem fixed.  Double check if is a [mcve].

Comment: @Adam Nevraumont I will do that next time. I thought the original example was 'minimal' enough, but it turned out not to be...